# Solve Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in helpers.php line 500

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to set up this laravel project on cpanel, and keep getting this error, I've read around and the posible solution is to update the php in the cpanel, but I don't know how to do that. I thought I did because when I do `php -v` in the PuTTY it says

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 28 2020 20:08:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

but I guess that's not right because I'm still getting the error.

Also when I check the cpanel server information it says `PHP Version` is `5.6.40`.

How do I fix this for good?

Comment: What is the code in `helpers.php` at line 500? Also, your CLI (command line) version of PHP can be different from the version serving your site.

Comment: @JeremyHarris `return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);` I think that is what is happening, the version in the cpanel is different from the one when I do `php -v`

Comment: The command line PHP might be different than the webserver PHP. Check if cPanel has any way to differentiate between the two

Comment: @apokryfos how can I update the php version that cpanel as a whole uses, in the `MultiPHP Manager` I can `Set PHP Version per Domain` and there I put the version as 7.1 but the `System PHP Version` still stays as 5.6

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it might be better setting up a domain to host your site and not have it as the system default site. I'm not that familiar with cPanel myself

Comment: @apokryfos it's not as the default site, this would be a subdomain on the server, this project is for my school and I need to make it work on this server, but like this I can't even do the composer install on it

Comment: @JeremyHarris do you know how to change the php version of the home directory?

Comment: You would need to edit your php.ini -- do you have ssh access? If you do not, it may be something you need your hosting provider to do for you.

Comment: @JeremyHarris could you look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062542/setup-laravel-project-on-cpanel