# Setup Laravel project on cPanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to set up a laravel project as a subdomain on cpanel but I'm getting parsing issues, and an error.

These are the steps I've done so far

- zip the project and upload it to this directory `public_html/encuestas`
- unzip and move contents to the directory above
- get ssh access with PuTTY and cd into the directory
- do this command in PuTTY `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

I've also done it all through the PuTTY, cloned the repository from bitbucket with the same results.

After the command I get this feedback

```
vc@un.net [~/public_html/encuestas]# composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/vc/public_html/encuestas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

And when I go to the subdomain `encuestas.un.ac.cr` this is the error I get

> Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I suspect the php versions are the problem, in cpanel I have set the php version of this domain to `PHP 7.1 (ea-php71)` and these errors still persist, however the PHP System Default is set as `5.6` (I don't know how to change it). This was the solution I found online for the parsing errors but this hasn't worked.

I'm completely lost as to what could be happening or how to fix it?

EDIT:
when doing composer update this is the result

```
vc@un.net [~/public_html/encuestas]# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.5 requires php >=7 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf 0.8.x-dev requires php >=7 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.5 requires php >=7 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.5 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[0.8.x-dev, v0.8.5].
```

Answer (score 1):

On that cPanel subdomain make sure to set the php version to at least `7.1.3` that can be done in cpanel itself in `MultiPHP Manager`

[image]

After that you will get a list of your subdomains, select it and from the top right choose a php version that works with that package at least(7.1.3) in your case, Click Apply.

[image]

> If you don't have that php version installed on your server then contact the Admin to activate or install it.
>
> If that didn't work, for the subdomain, try to set that PHP version to the root domain.
>
> If you have access to WHM you can install a new PHP version through the `easyApache` panel.
>
> Sometimes you have to restart Apache server in order for the new php to work.

Comment: I set it as the max shown to me that is 7.1, but these errors still come up

Comment: in putty try this command `php -v` it shold tell you which version you're actually using, let me know

Comment: if I'm in the home directory it says php 5.6.40, but if I cd into the directory for this project then it says 7.1.33

Comment: in that directory try this command `php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update`

Comment: Or, download the composer.phar from composer into that directory and use it after `php...` just to make sure that composer is using the php 7 not 5

Comment: another solution is setting the updating the php version for the root directory if it doesn't cause issues, set it to 7, do you have whm access?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have whm access, should I try that command in the project directory or the home directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207207/discussion-between-nancy-and-emad).